How to remove new line(s) from the long string
I have a file which consists of very long string about 300 over character. The string consists of space and new line characters.
The content of the file is as follow:
[EEPROM]
Logic EEPROM = 67 0 0 14 1 249 95 15 65 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 51 69 48 48 56 1 48 52 49 0 48 54 4 67 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 48 8 49 50 50 9 51 48 48 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 48 48 48 48 48 0 4 0 0 22 145 38 51 49 5 53 51 49 52 5 5 52 55 0 48 4 57 48 45 55 48 54 57 51 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 2 0 0 48 53 45 4 54 45 50 48 9 55 48 53 45 49 5 45 50 48 49 55 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
Data EEPROM = 140 0 0 226 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 219 2 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 219 2 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 6 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 219 2 15 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 219 2 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 10 1 1 0 1 50 0 1 219 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 19 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 19 2 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 18 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 19 2 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

I want to extract the data of "Logic EEPROM". I've tried to test with the following python code.
LogicEE_St = 'Logic EEPROM = '

fileToRead = 'C:\\Users\\Arduino\\Desktop\\Python\\Python_NSE\\Test.txt'

with open(fileToRead, 'r') as fp:  
    
    # read all lines in a list
    lines = fp.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        # check if string present on a current line
        if line.find(LogicEE_St) != -1:
            LogicEE_Ref_Line_1 = line          
            break
       
print(LogicEE_Ref_Line_1)
split_text = LogicEE_Ref_Line_1.replace('\n', '').replace('\r', '').replace(' \n', '').replace(' \r', '')
print(split_text)
split_text = LogicEE_Ref_Line_1.strip()
print(split_text)
print("\n".join(item for item in LogicEE_Ref_Line_1.split('\n') if item))

clean_text = "".join(split_text)
print(clean_text)

The result is not coming out with the one line. It is coming with new line character. I want to remove new line character only so that the string does not have new line character.
I've searched the web and try everything I can but it still does not work.
My python setup is as follow:
OS: Windows 10
Editor: Visual Studio Code
Python Version: 3.11.4 (64 bit)
Please use notepad++ or sublime text (without word wrap) to see the result as one line.

As you read each line, remove all/any trailing whitespace as follows:
LogicEE_St = 'Logic EEPROM = '

fileToRead = 'foo.txt'

with open(fileToRead) as fp:  
    for line in map(str.rstrip, fp):
        if line.startswith(LogicEE_St):
            # line will not have any trailing newline character(s)
            print(line)


Thank for the answer, I've tested your code, unfortunately, the result is with new line char. Did you check the result with notepad++ or sublime text (without word wrap)?

@AungKL the variable line will not contain any trailing whitespace. Of course, print() will add a newline for presentation purposes. You can suppress that with end=""

@AungKL adding on the the previous comment, you would want to do print(line, end='') to suppress the newline created by print().

Please refer to the attached picture, the value of line during debugging is showing without new line char, but after print(line) -> showing new line char, a bit confusing.

@AungKL We don't see any picture that you may have attached.  Can you elaborate what you are confused about? print() usually adds a newline character after the printing, so its normal that the printed text has an additional newline character even when line does not have prior to printing. As explained by SIGNUP, you need to suppress the newline that print() is adding by providing end='' (which I have show how in my previous comment).

@Aung If you want to share a screenshot, share a link to it in a comment. Don't edit the answer

@SIGHUP, I've put print(line, end=''). But it does not work. The original characters of the Logic EEPROM are 713 characters.  if I reduce the characters to 356 characters, it works. I think there is a limitation of print function. Thank you

use .rstrip("\n") and iterate by-lines instead!
when you open() a file in text mode (this is the default, rather than binary b) it'll become an io.TextIOWrapper()

TextIOWrapper dynamically replaces platform-specific newlines (such as the wacky Windows \r\n) with just \n when presented to your program
and is already an iterable by-lines for line in fh: ..., avoiding .readlines()

with open(path_file) as fh:
    for line in fh:
        if line.startswith("Logic EEPROM "):
            print(repr(line.rstrip("\n")))
            break  # no need to read any more lines
    else:  # didn't find and break
        raise Exception(f"failed to read Logic EEPROM from {path_file}")

>>> from io import StringIO  # hack to make text act like a file here
>>> data = StringIO("""[EEPROM]
... Logic EEPROM = 67 0 0 14 1 249 95 15 65 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 51 69 48 48 56 1 48 52 49 0 48 54 4 67 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 48 8 49 50 50 9 51 48 48 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 48 48 48 48 48 0 4 0 0 22 145 38 51 49 5 53 51 49 52 5 5 52 55 0 48 4 57 48 45 55 48 54 57 51 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 2 0 0 48 53 45 4 54 45 50 48 9 55 48 53 45 49 5 45 50 48 49 55 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
... Data EEPROM = 140 0 0 226 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 219 2 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 219 2 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 6 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 219 2 15 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 219 2 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 10 1 1 0 1 50 0 1 219 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 19 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 19 2 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 18 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 19 2 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
... """)
>>> for line in data:
...     if line.startswith("Logic EEPROM "):
...         print(repr(line.rstrip("\n")))
... 
'Logic EEPROM = 67 0 0 14 1 249 95 15 65 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 51 69 48 48 56 1 48 52 49 0 48 54 4 67 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 48 8 49 50 50 9 51 48 48 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 48 48 48 48 48 0 4 0 0 22 145 38 51 49 5 53 51 49 52 5 5 52 55 0 48 4 57 48 45 55 48 54 57 51 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 2 0 0 48 53 45 4 54 45 50 48 9 55 48 53 45 49 5 45 50 48 49 55 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0'


Thank for the answer, I've tested your code, unfortunately, the result is with new line char. Did you check the result with notepad++ or sublime text (without word wrap)?
